# Regex to catch groups of same digits in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, numbers, digits

Is it possible to catch all grous of same digits in string with regex on Ruby? I'm not familiar with regex.

I mean: regex on `"1112234444"` will produce `["111", "22", "3", "4444"]`

I know, I can use `(\d)(\1*)`, but it only gives me 2 groups in each match. `["1", "11"], ["2", "2"], ["3", -], ["4", "444"]`

How can I get 1 group in each match? Thanks.

Comment: Dave, yes, in this case it is important . I know how to solve it without regex, but I need regex, if it is possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here, give this a shot:

```
((\d)\2*)
```

Comment: Wow, good to know. How should it be called on `"1112234444"`? `"1112234444"[/((\d)\2*)/]` gives only "111". Thanks.

Comment: You can use "1112234444".scan(/((\d)\2*)/)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this regex

```
((\d)\2*)
```

group 1 catches your required value

Answer (score 1):

My first quick answer was rightfully criticized for having no explanation for the code. So here's another one, better in all respects ;-)

We exploit the fact that the elements whose runs we want are digits and they are easy to enumerate by hand. So we construct a readable regex which means "a run of zeros, or a run of ones, ... or a run of nines". And we use the right method for the job, [String#scan](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/scan):

```
irb> "1112234444".scan(/0+|1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+/)
=> ["111", "22", "3", "4444"]
```

For the record, here's my original answer:

```
irb> s = "1112234444"
=> "1112234444"
irb> rx = /(0+|1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+)/
=> /(0+|1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+)/
irb> s.split(rx).reject(&:empty?)
=> ["111", "22", "3", "4444"]
```

Comment: You should explain your post and what you do!